# use VLC to RTSP stream screen capture transcoded as MJPEG

Tags: vlc, rtsp, mjpeg

The command I used was;

```
vlc -vvv screen:// :sout="#transcode{vcodec=mjpg,acodec=none,fps=1}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://localhost:8554/stream0}"
```

when I try to play `rtsp://localhost:8554/stream0` with another VLC player, it seems VLC successfully connect to RTSP but soon after it terminates its connection with message `live555 error: no data received in 10s, aborting`

The plaform I use is Windows 10 Enterprise x64 10.0.18363, with VLC 3.0.8 Vetinari.